# cannot convert from 'AnonymousType#1' to 'int'

Tags: c#, anonymous-types

All I need to get all the team members ids so that I can query the contact table.

```
var teamMembersIds = (from q in _repository.GetQuery<TeamMember>
                               (t => teamIds.Contains(t.TeamId))
                                select new { q.ResourceContactId }
                     )
                    .ToList();
```

The problem is that I need to merge it with another anonymous list of ids.

```
resContactIds.AddRange(teamMembersIds);
```

I'm getting the following error:

I tried also this:

```
var resContactIds = new List<int>();
foreach (var _id in teamMembersIds)
{
   if(resContactIds.Contains(_id))
   {
      resContactIds.Add(_id);
   }
}
```

I'm getting the following error: `cannot convert from 'AnonymousType#1' to 'int'`

Comment: Just don't use the 'new' in your select statement - you are generating a new anonymous type. Instead, select q.ResourceContactId

Comment: When you say "another anonymous list of ids", what do you mean by anonymous?  The list appears to have a name, and the elements appear to have a named type,  specifically `int`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

With `select new { q.ResourceContactId }` you are selecting an anonymous type, if you want an `List<int>` then remove `new` and curly braces like::

```
var teamMembersIds = (from q in _repository.GetQuery<TeamMember>
                               (t => teamIds.Contains(t.TeamId))
                                select q.ResourceContactId //here
                     )
                    .ToList();
```

> The problem is that I need to merge it with another anonymous list of
>   ids

Your other list `resContactIds` is also `List<int>`, it is not a list of anonymous objects.

*One more thing to add, you can omit the call `ToList` in your first query since `AddRange` can accept `IEnumerable<T>`*

Comment: I'm so grateful as for the first time, i don't get the red squiggly. That's the reason I was often staying away of linq. Now, I know the role of the key work `new` Thanks again.